# Use ParametricNDSolve to solve ODEs with an if statement

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear

This is the first time I ask a question. I have seen many solutions and tried but they are not working.

Here is my code：

```
\[Rho]0=0.804462;
hd =5.85106;
h1[t_] := 
  a t^6 + b t^5 + c t^4 + d t^3 + e t^2 + f t + 
    g /. {a -> -84.60506925892892`, b -> -687.4080728208952`, 
    c -> 541.5803749714279`, d -> -93.12260744655956`, 
    e -> 8.825410660517237`, f -> -0.30672322150222175`, 
    g -> 0.0019530704018225935`};
h2[t_] := 
  a t^6 + b t^5 + c t^4 + d t^3 + e t^2 + f t + 
    g /. {a -> -101.96063553066904`, b -> 2163.7047632962763`, 
    c -> -16792.670259715913`, d -> 64772.396369720926`, 
    e -> -134372.90247543552`, f -> 144070.08998130512`, 
    g -> -62856.10200625046`};
T[p_] := a p^2 + b p + c /. {a -> 0.028928844262185633`, 
    b -> 3.076534419234442`, c -> 1571.5838936601692`};
q[p_] := Exp[0.15232537265544788` ArcTan[0.0022032984913644207` (106.34833494734309` + 2.` p)] - 0.25295964346433863`];
A[t_]:=Piecewise[{{\[Pi] ((h1[t] + 1.25 Cot[9 Degree])^2 Tan[9 Degree]^2),0 <= Mod[t, 100] < 0.369},
{0.7^2 \[Pi],0.369 <= Mod[t, 100] <= 2.08},
{\[Pi] ((h2[t] + 1.25 Cot[9 Degree])^2 Tan[9 Degree]^2),2.08 < Mod[t, 100] <= 2.45},
{0,2.45 < Mod[t, 100] <= 100}}];
v11[t_] := 0.85 A[t] Sqrt[(2 (-101.325 10^-3 + p[t]))/q[p[t]]];
vv2[t_] := (94.88535710795955`/2) Cos[\[Omega] t] + 134.88535710795955`/2;

f[t_] := (Sign[p2[t] - p[t]] + 1) (Sign[p2[t] - p[t]]);
v22[t_] := (0.85 0.25 \[Pi] 5^2 Sqrt[((f[t] (p2[t] - p[t]))/q[p2[t]]) ]);
eqn1 = p'[t] == 
   1/(12500.` \[Pi]) T[p[t]]/ q[p[t]] (q[p2[t]] v22[t] - q[p[t]] v11[t]);
eqn2 = If[(p2[t] > p[t]) // Evaluate, (D[q[p2[t]] vv2[t], t] + v11[t] q[p2[t]]) // Evaluate, (q[p2[t]] vv2[t] - \[Rho]0 \[Pi] 0.25 5^2 hd) // Evaluate] == 0;
ans = ParametricNDSolve[{eqn1,p[0] == 100, p2[0] == 0.5, eqn2}, {p, p2}, {t, 0, 10000}, {\[Omega]}, 
  Method -> {"EquationSimplification" -> "Residual"}]
```

But when i assign a value to the parameter，

```
p[0.027] /. ans
```

the following error is given：
[image]

I don't know how to solve the ODEs which in the case of piecewise equations,please help me.

Comment: h1 and h2 are not defined

Comment: I forgot to copy the code for these two functions before

Comment: "Piecewise" should have additional braces. And \[Rho]0 is not defined.

Comment: Sorry,i fogot it again, now the missing code has been fixed